# How to change command timeout in pywin32. 'Open' method

Tags: python, oledb, pywin32, connection-timeout, pywin

I've got the problem using pywin32 library and trying to connect to OLEDB.

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 35, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 31, in ado
  File "<COMObject ADODB.Recordset>", line 4, in Open
    the XML parser for analysis: the response Time for the XML for analysis request timed out before it was completed.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

I've tried to add `Connect Timeout=1000` to my `connectionstring` to no avail.

**Code**

```
import win32com.client
import pyodbc

conn = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
    DSN = CONNECTION_STRING
    conn.Open(DSN)

    rs = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')



        strsql = u"""
    select

        ...
        ...
        ...

        """

    h = rs.Open(strsql, conn,0,1)
    ts = rs.GetRows()
    conn.Close()
    return ts
```

I think that the problem is here:

```
h = rs.Open(strsql, conn,0,1)
```

I can't see which parameters should be passed to 'Open'. But I think it must have timeout parameter.

How can I change command timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding:

```
conn.CommandTimeout=3000
```